# How to make sure server completes the job within interval of cronjob?

Tags: time, cron, execution, schedule

Let's say I own an app that allows its users to schedule their emails.

What if 1 million users out of 10 million, schedule an email to send at exact 11:00 PM on same date (neglect time zone). Would the receiving ends get their email on exactly 11:00 PM?

**If yes**, then how is it possible and how to achieve this task in any language or framework without third party services?

**If no**, then I am assuming it is because it will take time to fetch data from database and then execution time for email propagation but I want to eliminate or minimize this time. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: "1 million users out of 10" does not work for integer algebra. Did you mean "10 out of a million"?

Comment: email is not a time-critical service that would be easy to be used as synchronous data-stream. If the notification time for users is that important, you should probably find other ways than using email.